# Folder action automator does not trigger on change but works manually

Tags: catalina, automator, folder-action

I have folder actions automators for 2 different folders.  One works automatically as expected, the other does not.  Both are constructed the same way and both run manually, but one does not run automatically when folder contents change.  Both execute a shell script with the following pattern:

```
cp -n /path/to/source/filename-v* /path/to/destination/
```

Where the folder action monitors changes the the respective folder and the script simply copies the new files to the respective destination folders.

[image]

**Both work when executed manually**, but one does not trigger on folder action like the other.

> What am I not understanding?  Is there another option for creating this type of automation without using automator?

It's possible that this is just buggy:

- [Why aren't any of my Folder Actions triggering?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90560/why-arent-any-of-my-folder-actions-triggering)
- [Unreliable Folder Action](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35642/unreliable-folder-action)

Furthermore

[image]